# Don't select value from column identical to value of another column in SQL

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, max

I have two columns from a table; **fromid** and **toid**, which contain the same user id on occasions.

I have also a dropdown select box which selects all the ids from both these columns.

My problem is that the dropdown selects all users, but also duplicates when one user is in both columns.

What I would like is to select only a user once and give one of the columns a priority or MAX(is that it?) if the user appears in both columns. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$sql="
                            SELECT
                                DISTINCT u.".($config->realnames ? "name" : "username")." AS displayname,
                                u.id 
                            FROM
                                (#__users AS u
                            INNER JOIN
                                #__uddeim AS um
                            ON
                                u.id=um.fromid)
                            WHERE
                                um.toid=".(int)$myself."
                            AND
                                um.totrash=0
                            AND
                                `um`.`delayed`=0".$filter."
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT
                                DISTINCT u.".($config->realnames ? "name" : "username")." AS displayname,
                                u.id
                            FROM
                                (#__users AS u
                            INNER JOIN
                                #__uddeim AS um
                            ON
                                u.id=um.toid)
                            WHERE
                                um.fromid=".(int)$myself."
                            AND
                                um.totrashoutbox=0".$filter."
                            AND um.systemflag=0";
```

---

WHAT I'VE TRIED -

I tried using a count query but this dind't work:

```
if (count ($row->displayname > 1))
    echo "duplicate rows";
```

Comment: Simplify your code, we do not need to see your entire query. Give us just the relevant code which emulated ONLY the problem you need help solving.

Comment: i tried using a count query but this didn't work, but i can't figure out any other solution: /*if (count ($row->displayname > 1))
 echo "duplicate rows";*/

Comment: I meant, remove ALL the unnecessary where/join/union selected fields in the above query you can reproduce the problem without. Too much white noise for anybody to want to help.

Comment: Try making a bit more effort then

Comment: ok its just last time I simplified my question, people were saying I need to provide more so that's what i did on this occasion. Next time, I'll be more specific, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `UNION ALL` in your query to just `UNION`. The former retains all rows from both datasets; the latter eliminates duplicates - it is a shortened form of `UNION DISTINCT`.